# Dynamic AngularJs directive by generated SVG element

Tags: angularjs, svg, d3.js

I have an HTML tag with AngularJs directive, like:

```
<div line-chart></div>
```

It calls a directive that generates a SVG object and its relative child elements. The function that is used to create a child element:

```
function drawDataPoints(params){
  function drawDataPointCircles() {
    var dataPointAttributes = {
      'class': 'data-point negative' 
    };

    params.svg.selectAll('circle data-point')
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('label-visible', '');
  }
  drawDataPointCircles();
}
```

the output of this directive is:

```
<svg class="chart">
  <g>
    <circle class="data-point negative" label-visible=""></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

as you may notice there is a `label-visible`  that should call the bellow directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('labelVisible', function () {
    debugger;
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element){

      }
    };
  });
```

but unfortunately the `labelVisible` directive is executed but the `link` function never gets called. Does anyone knows how to call `labelVisible` when generating svg element?

Comment: You'll need to compile it using the $compile service before appending it to the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Ethan Jewett for the hint to use `$compile` service.

Finally solved the problem. The issue was that when rendering the SVG element it is rendered as an ordinary string and not bound to the DOM. Thus the directive gets never called. So, what I needed to do is to call a $compile function, as @Ethan suggested, for each generated element and it will work, like:

```
    var point = params.svg.selectAll('circle data-point')
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('label-visible', '');

    $compile(point[0])(scope);
```